# Ignite cache becomes empty after system reboot

Tags: c#, ignite

Im playing with ignite and have simple test app to explore its persistence features:

```
using System;
using Apache.Ignite.Core;
using Apache.Ignite.Core.PersistentStore;

namespace IgniteDemo
{
    internal class Item
    {
        public int Number { get; set; }
        public DateTime PointInTime { get; set; }
        public override string ToString() => $"Item:{{Number={Number} ,PointInTime={PointInTime}}}";
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const string itemCacheName = @"Items";
            var random = new Random();

            var igniteConfig = new IgniteConfiguration{
                JvmInitialMemoryMb = 1024,
                PersistentStoreConfiguration = new PersistentStoreConfiguration()
            };

            using (var ignite = Ignition.Start(igniteConfig))
            {
                ignite.SetActive(true);

                var cache = ignite.GetOrCreateCache<Guid, Item>(itemCacheName);
                cache.LoadCache(null);

                // put random item into cache
                cache.Put(Guid.NewGuid(), new Item {Number = random.Next(), PointInTime = DateTime.Now});

                //print all items in the cache
                Console.WriteLine(@"Cache content:");
                foreach (var cacheEntry in cache)
                    Console.WriteLine(cacheEntry);

                Console.WriteLine("\nPress any key to Close");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Everything is ok. Data remains in the cache between application execution.
But if I reboot my system, all cache data becomes disappeared.
My first guess was that the problem happens due working directory in Temp folder by default. So i decided to move working directory to custom folder:

```
        var igniteConfig = new IgniteConfiguration
        {
            JvmInitialMemoryMb = 1024,
            WorkDirectory = @"D:\Store\Wd",
            PersistentStoreConfiguration = new PersistentStoreConfiguration()
            {
                PersistentStorePath = @"D:\Store\Data",
                WalStorePath = @"D:\Store\Wal",
                WalArchivePath = @"D:\Store\Wal\Archive"
            }
        };
```

And that was gain no results.

I have read official resources listed below

https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs

https://ptupitsyn.github.io/

But I still doesn't understand why my cache data disappears. Am I missed something important about Ignite persistance?

---

Im using NuGet to obtain Ignite and have Java 1.8.0_151 installed on my machine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at contents of `PersistentStorePath` folder, you'll see folders like `0_0_0_0_0_0_0_1_127_0_0_1_172_25_4_66_2001_0_9d38_6abd_388e_bade_3c6f_269_47500` (more details on name generation [here](http://apache-ignite-users.70518.x6.nabble.com/IgniteDataStreamer-with-Continuous-Query-td9779.html)).

Rebooting the machine causes this ID to change, this is a [known issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-6285) with Ignite 2.1 and 2.2 (fixed in upcoming 2.3). Workaround is to set `IgniteConfiguration.consistentId` property, but it is not available in `Ignite.NET` (also added in 2.3).

So your options are:

- Wait for Ignite 2.3 release, or use a [nightly build](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/IGNITE/Nightly+Builds)
- Set `consistentId` through [Spring XML](https://apacheignite-net.readme.io/docs/configuration#section-spring-xml) and load it with `IgniteConfiguration.SpringConfigUrl` property

Comment: Great! nightly build looks pretty good for me right now. Thank you!